# Ember get hasMany

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have Model

```
EmberApp.Card = DS.Model.extend({
  balance: DS.attr('number'),
  operations: DS.hasMany('operation', { async: true })
});
```

Than I make

```
self.store.find('card', 'me')
```

response

```
{ 
  "card": {
    "id": "53620486168e3e581cb5851a",
    "balance": 20
  }
}
```

getting card Model but without operations and setting it to controller prop "currentCard"
Then I want to find operations throw url /cards/me/operations
response

```
{"operation": [{ "id": 1, "type": 1 }] }
```

How can I do it from this.controllerFor('*').get('currentCard')... ?

Comment: You should make the call to ```store.find``` in the routes ```model()```-hook, and the you should be able to access it via ```this.get('content.operations').then(function (operations) {})``` inside the controller. Not sure though if this works since you are returning another ID when asking for the record with ID 'me'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should add links to response from cards/me

```
EmberApp.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  normalizePayload: function(type, payload) {
    if (type.toString() === 'EmberApp.Card') {
      payload.links = { 'operations': '/cards/me/operations' };
      return { card: payload };
    } else if (type.toString() === 'EmberApp.Operation') {
      return { operations: payload };
    }
 }
```

});

Then in route

```
EmberApp.CardOperationsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.controllerFor('sessions.new')
      .get('currentCard')
      .get('operations');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to return your operations as a list of ID's in your card response like this:

```
{ 
  "card": {
    "id": "53620486168e3e581cb5851a",
    "balance": 20,
    "operations": [1, 2, 3]
  }
}
```

This will enable you to do this in another route:

```
this.modelFor('card').get('operations');
```

or this in your cards controller:

```
this.get('content.operations');
```

This will execute the following call to your API:

```
/api/operations?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3
```

Comment: But if my api doesn't send me operations ids and also for operations I have url /cards/:id/operations ?

Comment: If you cannot conform to the way that Ember Data needs your payloads structured, you are going to need a custom adapter. Take a look at thsi project for an example https://github.com/toranb/ember-data-django-rest-adapter